# Can't get the binding object in a Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In a ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I create a Model Class named Task with its CRUD and in the index page wich list the tasks I need to modify each line separatly. So I create a form in each line. But when I submit a line I don't get the object Task in the action in the controller.

Here is the code :

Thanks

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.projectVersionList = this.getProjectVersionList();
            ViewBag.taskTypeList = this.getTaskTypeList();
            ViewBag.durationList = this.getDurationList();
            return View(db.Tasks.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(Task task)//task est instancié mais les propriétées sont vides
        {
            task.User = db.UserProfiles.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View(task);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<TimeSheet.Models.Task>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
    <div class="responsive-table-line">
    <table class="table table-striped" data-card-view="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectVersionId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaskTypeId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Accomplished)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Editor Template :**

```
@model TimeSheet.Models.Task

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<tr>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TaskId)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "datefield form-control", type = "date" })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.User.UserName)
    </td>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectVersionId)">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectVersionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.projectVersionList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaskTypeId)">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TaskTypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.taskTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration)">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Duration, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.durationList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Accomplished)">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Accomplished)
    </td>
    <td data-title="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-label="Left Align"></button>

        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = Model.TaskId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-edit" })

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true">  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id = Model.TaskId })</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = Model.TaskId })</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! I've found the pb : The fields in each forms are names "items.[propertyName]" instead of "[propertyName]".I replace in the view item by model like this

```
 @foreach (var model in Model)
        {
           @Html.EditorFor(m => model)
        }
```

And in EditorTemplace m by model

```
model => model.Accomplished
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need (and should not be using) the `@foreach` - if the model is `IEnumerable<Task>` and the template is `@model Task` then it should be just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m);` (not in a loop)